# how i can get count as 0 if no records?

Tags: mysql, date

I have a query like this

```
select `temp`, IfNULL(count(id),0) t 
from survey 
where `temp`<>'NULL' and `temp`<> '' and date(submitdate)='date' 
group by `temp
```

with o/p

```
temp        t
A1          1
```

But here is what happens on the selected date, if there are no records: I'm not getting any results. answers are like A1,A2,A3

I need o/p like this

```
temp   t
A1     1
A2     0
A3     0
```

Comment: You must be having a different table which has all the types of 'temp', like A1, A2..
I mean
which table are you reffering to get A1, A2, A3

Comment: You're comparing to the string 'NULL' rather than records where the column is NULL - is this intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do some self-`JOIN` tricks to get a record for every answer:

```
SELECT s.`temp`, count(survey.id) t
-- This will ensure that you will get all relevant answers A1, A2, A3
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT `temp`
  FROM survey
  WHERE `temp` <> 'NULL' and `temp` <> ''
--             ^^^^^^^^^ Might want to replace this by `temp` IS NOT NULL?
) s
-- Only then, you will actually get the actual records per answer and date
LEFT OUTER JOIN survey
  ON s.`temp` = survey.`temp`
  AND date(survey.submitdate) = 'date'
GROUP BY s.`temp`
```

Just be sure that you have an index on `survey.temp`.